# is it possible to "provision domain" using "Azure CLI"?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

am new to Azure CLI, and my main task is to automate provisioning domains to my "Email Communication Service"
I already found a way create/purchase a domain name and update the DNS records from my domain name provider (namecheap) using their API service for developers.
I checked the documentation and I couldn't find any resources so am wondering am looking in the wrong place or that I don't know how to look.
Microsoft give the impression that you can do everything on the CLI, so am not sure if this one is included or if I have to go through the tedious process of doing it manually which takes alot of time and frusturation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `az appservice domain create` CLI command

For example:

```
az appservice domain create -g MyResourceGroup --hostname MyCustomDomain.com --contact-info=@'C:/path_to_contact_info.json' --accept-terms
```

> --accept-terms: to accept the legal terms for purchasing and creating the domain.

For more info. please read through [Azure Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/domain?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: that's for something else, I already have a custom domain purchased from another provider, I don't want to buy it from microsoft.
so I don't want to "purchase" as the official doc says, I want to "provision" that domain into the: email communication service